# how to include marker click for this info window in ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

This is just part of my code for ajax call, as I want to include click event to marker here:

```
var loaddata = function(place) {
    var venue_id = place.venue_id;
    var client_id = "LGHIIR3H5N4LB4X5GLRZOWCVWTP5DPAFBA4NZH02GG2BKWJE";
    var client_secret = "KY3VVWMVCCPZLDKVVYUSWJIZ0JXNZIHVCXX3S5PCRERYMEYP";
    var FoursquareUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/" + venue_id + "?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&v=20130815";

    $.ajax({
        url: FoursquareUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true
    }).success(function(data) {

        place.name = data.response.venue.name;
        place.rating = data.response.venue.rating;

        if (place.rating !== undefined) {
            place.rating = data.response.venue.rating;
        } else {
            place.rating = 'Not Avaliable';
        }
        console.log(place.name);
        console.log(place.rating);
        var image_prefix = data.response.venue.bestPhoto.prefix;
        var image_suffix = data.response.venue.bestPhoto.suffix;

        console.log(image_prefix + "320x200" + image_suffix);
        var imag = image_prefix + "320x200" + image_suffix;


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5>' + ' <p>' + place.rating + '</p>' + "<img src=" + imag + ">" + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, place.marker);
        new google.maps.event.trigger(place.marker, 'click');

        //can i include marker click event 

    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert('Failed to get FOURSQUARE api');
    });

};
```

Here I need to show my infowindow when markers get clicked. Can I include click event inside ajax success?

Comment: here i need to show my infowindow when markers get clicked can i include  click event inside ajax success

Comment: or what para to pass in my click event while including loadata() in it

Comment: Where is the marker defined?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is the use of a clousure  (in this case the addListenersOnMyMarker function)

```
var loaddata = function(place) {
    var venue_id = place.venue_id;
    var client_id = "LGHIIR3H5N4LB4X5GLRZOWCVWTP5DPAFBA4NZH02GG2BKWJE";
    var client_secret = "KY3VVWMVCCPZLDKVVYUSWJIZ0JXNZIHVCXX3S5PCRERYMEYP";
    var FoursquareUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/" + venue_id + "?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&v=20130815";

    $.ajax({
        url: FoursquareUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true
    }).success(function(data) {

        place.name = data.response.venue.name;
        place.rating = data.response.venue.rating;

        if (place.rating !== undefined) {
            place.rating = data.response.venue.rating;
        } else {
            place.rating = 'Not Avaliable';
        }
        console.log(place.name);
        console.log(place.rating);
        var image_prefix = data.response.venue.bestPhoto.prefix;
        var image_suffix = data.response.venue.bestPhoto.suffix;

        console.log(image_prefix + "320x200" + image_suffix);
        var imag = image_prefix + "320x200" + image_suffix;


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
          });


        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + '<h5>' + place.name + '</h5>' + ' <p>' + place.rating + '</p>' + "<img src=" + imag + ">" + '</div>');
        //infowindow.open(map, place.marker);
        //new google.maps.event.trigger(place.marker, 'click');


        var addListenersOnMyMarker = function(map, marker, inforwindo) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });  
        };

       addListenersOnMyMarker(aMarker, aInfoIfoWindow );


        //can i include marker click event 

    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert('Failed to get FOURSQUARE api');
    });

};
```